# obter dados de mysql usando javascript e ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um web app [(caso interesse, segue link)](http://parapinski.com/content/calc-st/calc-st.html) e estava indo tudo certo, até eu chegar na parte abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O campo **NCM** é uma tag `input` com um atributo disabled. A informação dentro dela vem de um auto complete que usei, usando o **AJAX**, um banco de dados um arquivo busca.php para retornar os dados em json.

**OS PROBLEMAS**

Estou usando o seguinte código php para acessar o banco de dados e retornar os dados
*(ps: ja existe uma tabela, no mesmo banco de dados, referente ao primeiro autocomplete)*

```
            <?php 
            // Dados da conexão com o banco de dados
            define('SERVER', 'xxx');
            define('DBNAME', 'cl36-rickpara');
            define('USER', 'xxx');
            define('PASSWORD', 'xxx');

            // Recebe os parâmetros enviados via GET
            $acao = (isset($_GET['acao'])) ? $_GET['acao'] : '';
            $parametro = (isset($_GET['parametro'])) ? $_GET['parametro'] : '';

            // Configura uma conexão com o banco de dados
            $opcoes = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8');
            $conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVER."; dbname=".DBNAME, USER, PASSWORD, $opcoes);

            // Verifica se foi solicitado uma consulta para o autocomplete
            if($acao == 'autocomplete'):
                $where = (!empty($parametro)) ? 'WHERE codigo_item LIKE ?' : '';
                $sql = "SELECT codigo_item, descricao_item, aliq_ipi, ncm FROM base_prod " . $where;



            $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
            $stm->bindValue(1, $parametro.'%');
            $stm->execute();
            $dados = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            $json = json_encode($dados);
            echo $json;
            endif;

            // Verifica se foi solicitado uma consulta para preencher os campos do formulário
                if($acao == 'consulta'):
                    $sql = "SELECT codigo_item, descricao_item, aliq_ipi, ncm   FROM base_prod ";
                $sql .= "WHERE codigo_item LIKE ? LIMIT 1";

                $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
                $stm->bindValue(1, $parametro.'%');
                $stm->execute();
                $dados = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                $json = json_encode($dados);
                echo $json;
                endif;

            // Verifica se foi solicitado uma consulta para preencher o mva
                if($acao == 'consulta'):
                $sqlz = "SELECT ncm, rs, sc, sc_simples, rj, mg, mt, ap FROM nmcMVA " . $where; 
                $sqlz .= "WHERE ncm LIKE ? LIMIT 1";

                $stm = $conexao->prepare($sqlz);
                $stm->bindValue(1, $parametro.'%');
                $stm->execute();
                $dados = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                $json = json_encode($dados);
                echo $json;
                endif;
```

E o seguinte javascript (jquery) para o AJAX consultar os dados:

```
            $(function() {

                // Atribui evento e função para limpeza dos campos
                $('#busca').on('input', limpaCampos);

                // Dispara o Autocomplete a partir do segundo caracter
                $( "#busca" ).autocomplete({
                    minLength: 2,
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "consulta.php",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {
                                acao: 'autocomplete',
                                parametro: $('#busca').val()
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                response(data);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    focus: function( event, ui ) {
                        $("#busca").val( ui.item.codigo_item );
                        carregarDados();
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
              $("#codigoItem").val(ui.item.codigo_item);
              $("#descricao").val(ui.item.descricao_item);
              $("#aliqIPI").val(ui.item.aliq_ipi);
              $("#ncm").val( ui.item.ncm);
              return false;
            }
                })
                .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                    return $( "<li>" )
                    .append( item.codigo_item+ " — " + item.descricao_item )
                    .appendTo( ul );
                };

                // Função para carregar os dados da consulta nos respectivos campos
                function carregarDados(){
                    var busca = $('#busca').val();

                    if(busca != "" && busca.length >= 2){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "consulta.php",
                            dataType: "json",   
                            data: {
                                acao: 'consulta',
                                parametro: $('#busca').val()
                            },
                            success: function( data ) {
                                $('#codigoItem').val(data[0].codigo_item);
                                $('#descricao').val(data[0].descricao_item);
                                $('#aliqIPI').val(data[0].aliq_ipi);
                                $('#ncm').val(data[0].ncm);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

               //Função para carregar os dados da consulta no campo MVA
                function carregarDados(){
                    var busca = $('#ncm').val();

                    if(busca = $('#ncm').val()){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "consulta.php",
                            dataType: "json",   
                            data: {
                                acao: 'consulta',
                                parametro: $('#ncm').val()
                            },
                            success: function( data ) {
                                $('#mva').val(data[0].rs);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }


                // Função para limpar os campos caso a busca esteja vazia

                function limpaCampos(){
                    var busca = $('#busca').val();
                    if(busca == ""){
                        $('#codigoItem').value('');
                        $('#busca').val('');
                        $('#descricao').val('')
                        $('#aliqIPI').val('');

                    }
                }
            });
```

Os dados obitidos deveriam aparecer nas tags html correspondente

```html
     <p><span class="labelFake">NCM: </span><input type="text" id="ncm" disabled></p>
    <p><span class="labelFake">MVA: </span><input type="text" id="mva" disabled></p>
```

Mas, conforme a imagem, o campo MVA não esta sendo preenchido com as informações do banco de dados.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: De um console.log() no JSON que é retornado e veja se ele está vindo em branco ou preenchido, dessa forma você consegue descobrir se o erro é no front ou no back.

Comment: Recomendo você a tirar o `dataType: "json",` do jQuery e dar um alert na variável data em success. Eu acho que isso possa ser erro back end se a exibição de erros do PHP estiver ativa, possivelmente ela está sendo retornada junto com o objeto JSON.

Comment: O código tem 2 funções com o mesmo nome `carregarDados`. A segunda irá reescrever a primeira.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, na sua query no banco não tem o referido campo MVA.

Na sua interface também não tem um elemento mva. `$('#mva')` será sempre null.

Portanto, não vejo como funcionar como você deseja.

Se eu entendi errado, explique melhor seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Quando está "disabled", não guarda. Experimenta no HTML retirar o disabled.

```
<p><span class="labelFake">MVA: </span><input type="text" id="mva"></p>
```

Copia e corre, vê se funcionou. A solução é colocar uma disabled, e outra a calcular por trás no php sem o user ver.